# cocos2d-x undunderstand the image /screen /proportion, relative size between the opengl windows simulator and real device

Tags: c++, iphone, window, cocos2d-x

after long and many hours of development only on the windows opengl simulator using visual studio 2012 
every thing looked like it should be i tested on 480/320 screen size

```
CCSize screenSize = pEGLView->getFrameSize();
    CCSize designSize = CCSize(320, 480);

    CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->setDesignResolutionSize(designSize.width, designSize.height, kResolutionShowAll);

    if (screenSize.width > 640) {
        CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->addSearchPath("ipadhd");
        pDirector->setContentScaleFactor(1280/designSize.width);
    } else if (screenSize.width > 320) {
        CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->addSearchPath("ipad");
        pDirector->setContentScaleFactor(640/designSize.width);
    } else {
        CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->addSearchPath("iphone");
        pDirector->setContentScaleFactor(320/designSize.width);
    }
```

and with this function that loads the images

```
void GameLayer::loadImages()
{
    CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("sprites35.plist");
    m_gameBatchNode  = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("sprites.png",200);
    this->addChild(m_gameBatchNode,2,kSSheet);
    m_background  = CCSprite::create("gride300_300.png");
    m_background->setPosition(ccp(m_winSize.width/2,m_winSize.height/2));  
    this->addChild(m_background,kGrid);

}
```

when i first run the app in my device ( iPhone 5 ) 
all sizes of the images got 1/3 smaller and the position was all wrong .
my question is how can i develop on windows using the open GL simulator and still to see every thing right on my iPhone 5
**UPDATE**
i will give more info 
for example i have background image that is 297 x 297 Pixels (1.00) in size 
i place it like this :

```
m_background  = CCSprite::create("gride300_300.png");
m_background->setPosition(ccp(m_winSize.width/2,m_winSize.height/2));  
this->addChild(m_background,kGrid);
```

in the simulator it looks great . but when i see it in the iPhone it in the middle but very small . not like in the simulator

second example:
i place round gems with size : 35 x 35 Pixels (1.00) each to place in the middle also 
one after the other they all look great in the simulator but when i see it in the iPhone they are again very small
and align to the bottom left of the screen ,
here is the code to place the gems :

```
void Gem::placeInGride()
{
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteBatchNode = (CCSpriteBatchNode*) getGameController()->getGameLayer()->getChildByTag(kSSheet);
    int gemSelect =(rand() % totalGemsAvailable) + 1;

    GemType gemNum;
    gemNum =(GemType)gemSelect;
    setGemState(kGemNew);    
    char spritename[20];    
    sprintf(spritename,"gem%i_tranc.png",gemNum); 
    setImageName(spritename);
    setGemType(gemNum);    
    char spriteid[20];    
    sprintf(spriteid,"gem_%i_%i",getRowNum(),getColNum()); 
    std::string gemid(spriteid);
    setGemId(spriteid);
    mySprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(spritename);
    mySprite->setOpacity(255);
    spriteBatchNode->addChild(mySprite, 2);

    CCSize sSize = mySprite->getContentSize();
    setGemPosition(setPositionForGem(getRowNum(),getColNum(),sSize));

}

CCPoint Gem::setPositionForGem(int row,int col,const CCSize& gemSize)
{

    float leftPadding = 30 ; 
    float rightPadding = 37.5 ;
    float topPadding = 111.5;
    float buttonPadding = 90;
    float gemHight = gemSize.height;
    float gemWidth = gemSize.width;

    float x = (leftPadding+1) + ((gemWidth+2)*(col));
    float y = (topPadding+1)  + ((gemHight+2)*(row/*+1*/));
    return  ccp(x,y) ;

}
```

m attaching screen shots both from my iPhone and windows

[iphone_screen.PNG](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/attachments/2280/iphone_screen.PNG)
[windos_screen.jpg](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/attachments/2281/windos_screen.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your parameters backward for

```
CCSize designSize = CCSize(320, 480);
```

should be

```
CCSize designSize = CCSize(480,320);
```

also have you tried using

```
CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
```

to verify the  actual screen size being used for the device
then then providing scaled images from there like in [this example that uses the iphone, ipad and ipadhd](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Multi_resolution_support).